# ScrolledComposite children not populating content

Tags: java, swt

I have a ScrolledComposite widget that I'm initializing inside a selection listener (in turn attached to another composite). This ScrolledComposite contains in turn another Composite, which in turn holds a Button and a Label. While the internal composite appears, none of its children widgets do. I've used ScrolledComposite plenty of times before, and everything looks right to my eye. Can any of you see anything wrong? Note, the ScrolledComposite is a class variable. Also note that this problem is occurring regardless of if I ever dispose of the composite and its contents in the else condition.

```
    final Button showConsole = new Button(topLeft, SWT.CHECK);
    showConsole.setText("Show Debug Console");
    showConsole.setFont(new Font(domains.getDisplay(), "Segoe UI", 9, SWT.ITALIC));
    showConsole.setSelection(false);
    showConsole.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            //The total widget group is only supposed to appear when the button is selected
            if (showConsole.getSelection()) {
                scrolledConsoleComp = new ScrolledComposite(leftComposite,
                        SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
                Composite consoleComposite = new ScrolledComposite(scrolledConsoleComp, SWT.NONE | SWT.BORDER);
                consoleComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());
                consoleComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
                consoleComposite.setVisible(true);

                scrolledConsoleComp.setContent(consoleComposite);
                scrolledConsoleComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
                scrolledConsoleComp.setExpandVertical(true);
                scrolledConsoleComp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
                scrolledConsoleComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

                Button clear = new Button(consoleComposite, SWT.PUSH);
                clear.setText("Clear Console");

                final Label consoleText = new Label(consoleComposite, SWT.WRAP);
                consoleText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
                consoleText.setText("Messages: \n" + consoleData);
                clear.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                        consoleData = "";
                        consoleText.setText("Messages: \n" + consoleData);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    }
                }); 
                scrolledConsoleComp.setMinSize(leftComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
                leftComposite.layout(true);

            } else {

                scrolledConsoleComp.setVisible(false);
                scrolledConsoleComp.dispose();
                leftComposite.layout(true);
            }
        }
```

I appreciate any insight. Let me know if anything in this question is unclear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your `Button` and your `Label` inside a `ScrolledComposite`. They won't be shown because `setContent()` is not called.

Usually a `ScrolledComposite` contains a `Composite` that holds all the other Widgets.

Your `consoleComposite` should become a `Composite`.
No need for a call to `setVisible()`

Comment: Ah, so setContent() needs to be called on all widgets? I was thinking it would only need to happen with the Composite. Shows what I know. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sarah, actually you misunderstood. Only a ScrolledComposite has a setContent() method.

Comment: `setContent` needs to be called on all `ScrolledComposite` - your `consoleComposite` is actually a `ScrolledComposite` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean "called on." I mean, "called using." Ie, setContent(consoleText), setContent(clear), etc.

Comment: @greg-449 Ah, yes, my bad. That was a holdover from a previous test that I forgot to revert. With any luck, that is the source of my trouble. Yes, that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: setContent() accept only a single widget, and every call will overwrite the others.

Comment: As I said. You should convert you consoleComposite to a Composite